# How do I displace instances's vertices with geometry nodes fields?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to displace a surface with geometry nodes then make an instance out of it like this:
[image]

But when I instance this plane the noise repeats like this:

[image]

If I try to apply the displacement after the instances are made it will then look like this:

[image]

No matter what I do I can't get both of these to make something that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to apply displacement to these instances to achieve the above result?
These are my nodes:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution!

Using the Realize Instances node will not make a instance of the plane but a duplicate instead. this will "realize" the instance and turn it into individual mesh.

The reason the noise would repeat in a pattern way was because it was making a copy of that mesh, so by turning the instance into real mesh the noise now would apply as expected

[image]

[image]